# go-cd - run basic linux commands (cd, etc) in GoCD at task level

Tags: go-cd

I have had a good amount of experience using GoCD. I previously used bash scripts to generate builds and was successful as well. For some reason, I have to use basic linux commands as individual tasks.

What I have done successfully:

1. Pipeline1 - > Stage1 > Job1 > Task 1 : git clone my-project
2. Pipeline1 - > Stage1 > Job1 > Task 2 : bash my-project/script.sh

What I want to achieve:

1. Pipeline1 - > Stage1 > Job1 > Task 1 : git clone my-project2
2. Pipeline1 - > Stage1 > Job1 > Task 2 : cd my-project2
3. Pipeline1 - > Stage1 > Job1 > Task 3 : build package (*tar.gz file)
4. Pipeline1 - > Stage1 > Job1 > Task 4 : mkdir newDirectory/
5. Pipeline1 - > Stage1 > Job1 > Task 5 : mv *tar.gz newDirectory/

Whilst I am able to achieve task 1,3,4; but for commands like `cd, mv`, I get error like `check if agent can run cd`, `cannot find the file` (when I run the `mv` cmd as it is in terminal it works!) respectively.

I came across [GoCD Command Respository](https://docs.gocd.org/current/advanced_usage/command_repository.html), but I am not sure how would it help me. Can anyone help if you faced the same situation earlier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone was looking for the answer!

Okay, so I was playing around settings and found the field of 'Working directory' while creating a new task. here you can specify the directory where you want to run your command relative to where git checks out the materials. This serves te purpose of `cd`.

Will update this answer when I get something for `mv`.

Thanks!